# Git commit showing in wrong branch

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm working with Git through Visual Studio and I noticed a few commits that exist on *branch-a*, but are showing up in the history of my master branch. *branch-a* was never merged into master and I made sure that I have the latest code, so this is unexpected behavior.

The commits exist on master on Visual Studio Online, but not through VS's Team Explorer. I see the the commits when I run `git log` (in the command prompt) for master, and *branch-a* comes up when I run `git branch --merged master` .

Last strange piece of evidence: I manually searched the code for the changes made in these commits, and I see no trace of them. I searched my local code and the code on Visual Studio Online.

Can anyone please explain to me why this might be happening?

Much appreciated!

EDIT:
Here are the results of
`git log --graph --decorate --oneline --boundary master...branch-a`

```
* dcb976b (HEAD, branch-a) Refactoring export method for CA Sick Hours Repor
* dba6163 Added functional query to CA Sick Hours Report
* 705d108 Adding CA Sick Hours Report under the reports dropdown. Placeholder va
| *   95d2ac0 (origin/remote-checks-create-folder-on-project-save, origin/master
| |\
| | * cbf1dc7 (origin/project-payrun-list-report, project-payrun-list-report) Ad
| | * 7bfd8b0 Adding Project Pay Run List report (replacing the one available on
| * |   a83b229 Merge pull request 73 from mgmt-file-additions into master
| |\ \
| | * | 9ca1710 Moving format string into a const variable
| | * | 22baa60 Editing Management File: Parent Company column is now parent-mos
| * | | 0fb1d1e Replacing Min with Max to handle case where only some cells were
| * | |   fbbe9c7 Merge pull request 72 from hf-improve-db-connection-resiliency
| |\ \ \
| | |_|/
| |/| |
| | * | 0b6d09c (origin/hf-improve-db-connection-resiliency) Refactoring some co
| | * | 7f3d625 Replacing the last SqlConnection's with ReliableSqlConnection's.
| | * | 9f1ed46 Logging retry attemtps to windows event log.
| | * | 2069f5e Adding custom transient error detection for the ADO part of the
| | * | 59550c6 Refactoring several methods to use the new ReliableSqlConnection
| | * | d14a7ba Adding ReliableSqlConnection to JFA.DL.
| | * | f53c2bd Removing manual transactions (EF).
| | * | a2184e4 Adding resiliency execution strategy.
| * | |   2a2cbc2 Merge pull request 70 from hf-p-and-w-custom-report into maste
| |\ \ \
| | |_|/
| |/| |
| | * | 7665d98 (origin/hf-p-and-w-custom-report) Fixing several issues with the
| | * | c5d5605 Adding logic to gather P&W Cost Report data.
| | * | 2a631d4 half-baked EOR report changes from call with Carlos
| | * | 2cb9440 Adding method to generate P&W Costs Report content.
| | * | 03040f5 Adding code to print P&W Costs Report.
| | * | 85c76ee Adding P&W custom report.
| * | | 2d1b2b8 (tag: v1.9.4) Adding flat amount timesheet items to the sick hou
| * | | 5a4f57f (origin/hf-sick-hours-accruing-unprocessed-timesheets) Hiding "P
| * | | d3af8e5 Logging cause of application end.
| * | | 49b7ca6 Using fully processed timesheets only to calculate sick hours.
| * | | b98dc8e (origin/set-code-import, set-code-import) Fixing issue with cust
| | |/
| |/|
| * |   402e16f Merge pull request 71 from mgmt-report-add-parent-co-column into
| |\ \
|/ / /
| * | e023583 Adding parent company column to Management -> Generate Payroll Fil
| | o 0234afb Optimizing query (fringe deduction only).
o | e1afdf9 (tag: v1.9.3) Fixing issue with the ADP QTRLY File CAPs.
|/
o d383d04 (tag: v1.9.2) Fixing issue with exempt taxes.
```

Comment: May need some more info to help... Perhaps the output of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --date=relative --all`

Comment: Please post the output of `git log --graph --decorate --oneline  --boundary master...branch-a` ([three dots, we're after all commits on each branch back to their most recent merge base](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_triple_dot)) (edit: oops, commented w/o reloading, i.e. before seeing rholmes's. still, the limiter's worth using here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking carefully at the commit history, I noticed that this is what actually happened here:

**Developer A** merged *branch-a* into development
    [development now includes the commit]
**Developer B** branched *branch-b* from development
    [*branch-b* now includes the commit]
**Developer B** merged *branch-b* into master
    [but only included specific items from *branch-b*]
    [master now includes the commit, but no code/changes from the commit]

So I'll trust the history from the command line / Visual Studio Online. I'm going to assume that Team Explorer is not showing the commit because of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Common sense would suggest that one of your views into your code base is outdated.

I would tend to trust the result of the git command line query (which states that branch-a has indeed been committed into master). Based on that assumption my suggestion would be that your VS Team Explorer is displaying an outdated git status.

Depending on the detail of the commit messages employed by your team you may be able to see when and by whom the branch was merged into master. This might give you some insight into how it was merged, and therefore avoid the sequence of events that led to the incorrect merge.

Comment: Easy way for that to happen is there are multiple repos involved and OP's looking at different ones with the different tools.